# Adding a duration to a time in Excel

Tags: excel, time, duration

I'm a beginner with Excel. I am trying to create a list of tasks with a duration and add it to a time. What I mean is: I have a list of tasks, each one with a start time and a duration. I want to populate an end time for the task based on the duration, and then put that end time as the start time for the next task.

Example:

```
Clean teeth; Duration: 5 mins; Start time: 7:00am
```

| Task | Duration | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task1 | 5 mins | 7:00AM | 7:05AM |
| Task2 | 5 mins | 7:05AM | 7:10AM |

etc. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is given here - https://www.extendoffice.com/excel/formulas/excel-formula-add-minutes-to-time.html

> Start_time+TIME(0,minutes,0)

For example, there is a time data in cell B3, and the number of minutes you want to add is displayed in cell C3, please use below formula:

> =B3+TIME(0,C3,0)

Or

> =B3+TIME(0,36,0)

[image]